# Finding a value between different columns in Excel

Tags: python

I would like to find the solution to find the Pos that the user choose, then the user gives also a price and the program give him

I've tried:

```
V=data.query("KIO" & "UYT")['KIO'].max()
print(data['KIO'])
print(V)
V=data['GREER'].to_numpy()[data['UYT'].to_numpy() & data['HYEU'].to_numpy()].max()
print(V)
```